# fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD^': unknown revision or path not in the working tree when using git diff

Tags: git

I am trying to take out git diff of a particular file in a folder using below command on azure devops pipeline:

```
git diff --name-only HEAD^ .\dev-artifacts.properties .\dev-artifacts.properties
```

or

```
git diff --name-status HEAD HEAD^
```

or

```
git diff --name-only dev-artifacts.properties dev-artifacts.properties
```

After running this command, I am getting below error:

> fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD^': unknown revision or path not in the
> working tree. Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
> 'git  [...] -- [...]'

I tried switching the branch (main branch), but still it is not working. But in my local I am able to get the difference using git diff.

I want to get the difference using git diff, so that I can run a python script when there is a change in file.

Comment: Do you have a shallow clone with only a single commit? (`git rev-parse --is-shallow-repository`)

Comment: I have tried this command on my local : git rev-parse --is-shallow-repository, I am getting false as a result

Comment: Running the above command provided by you on my azure pipeline, I am getting true

Comment: There you have it: commit `HEAD^` does not exist in your pipeline. You have to deepen/unshallow your history first

Comment: I have unshallowed the git repo using this command : git fetch --unshallow and now it is working, really thank you so much. I was struggling from past 4hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a shallow repository with only a single commit. You can verify by executing `git rev-parse --is-shallow-repository`.

`HEAD^` points to the commit before your current commit – which does not exist in shallow clones of depth 1. You have to unshallow your clone or deepen it to include the commits which you are referencing.

For instance, to deepen your shallow clone to include the latest 5 commits, run `git fetch --depth=5`

Comment: I have unshallowed the git repo using this command : git fetch --unshallow and now it is working.

Comment: Hi, After unswallowing the repo it started working but the weird part is git diff is running but there is no output and not even a error.

Comment: @AbhishekSingh perhaps there are no changes? What is the exact diff command that you are executing?

Comment: git diff --name-only, I have done some changes as well to the files and checked, but no output

Comment: @AbhishekSingh this will not show changes from commits, but only changes between the working tree and the index. The OP question was about diffing commits (`HEAD^`). `git diff --name-only` does _not_ diff against a commit (only against the index).

Comment: So how I can get this done?

Comment: @AbhishekSingh get _what_ done? To diff two commits, use `git diff commitA commitB` (with any options that you require). Under the question you commented "and now it is working", so I don't know what is not working